# Is it possible to attach a non-console Win32 application to the invoking cmd shell?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, console-application, cmd

When I have a Win32 non-console application (AFAIK, the console-ness of a Win32 app is linked into the exe), starting it from the console `cmd.exe` will return to the command prompt immediately, running the application "in the background" (o.c. it can have a GUI of sorts, or even open its own console window)

Is it possible in the non-console executable to detect that it was launched from cmd.exe and "attach" it to the launching cmd.exe?

And note that there are various questions/answers related to this, but it seems that this exact approach hasn't been investigated. (Maybe it's not possible like that.)

Comment: It just doesn't work well in practice, your user would have to use "start /wait yourapp.exe" to avoid the processes fighting over the console.  The simple and never-fail way is to put a /Subsystem:Console build of your app in the path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this very easily. Simply pass `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS` to [`AttachConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952.aspx).

Whether or not the end result is sensible or practical is something I could not say. Both processes would read and write to the same console which could get pretty weird.

Comment: And that would make sense? The cmd.exe process wouldn't be aware of the attached other process, would it? Both process would write and read independently from the same console?

Comment: I'm not sure it would make sense. As you say, both processes can use the same console.

Comment: And if somebody closed the console window, the application that attached to it would be closed, too.