# Possible to have Win32 application block until it exits?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

When I open a command line in Windows (`cmd`) and start a program, for example `calc`, the prompt immediately returns and the program is started (the calculator window is displayed).

This is contrary to how I know it from the Linux world: when I start a (possibly with GUI) application, the prompt does not return until I exit the started program.

[image: Example: calculator is still running, but the user can already enter new commands at the prompt]

Using the w32 api, is it possible to program it so that my app displays a window, but the prompt is only returned after the user closes the window?

Comment: You need to mark it as a console application in the manifest.

Comment: Just saying you can use `start /wait` to wait for any application.

Comment: Marking it as a console application is probably not what I want, because that would always open a console, even if the program is started from say the task bar, right?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about `start /wait`!

Comment: Do you have a very good reason to do this? Linux and Windows are different. You shouldn't artificially force an application to behave in a way that is not usual for the system it runs on, unless there is a clear need for your application. Your users will be expecting the standard behaviour.

Comment: Start by looking at [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @JBentley I do find the Windows way strange (for example, if two programs are started from the same console window, their outputs will probably get mangled together), but you're right in that the app should behave as expected. If it is possible, I will not make it the default.

Comment: Related to [Is it possible to attach a non-console Win32 application to the invoking cmd shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621542/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-non-console-win32-application-to-the-invoking-cmd-she?rq=1), although my question is not answered there, either.

Comment: A native Windows app creates its own window.  There is therefore no point at all in disabling the command interpreter, it is available to run another command.

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, in the *nix world you normally expect to have stdio available for all programs. For example a interactive plotter may expect its data to plot on stdin.

Comment: @datenwolf: if you need the standard I/O handles, there's no reason not to make it a console application.  (Console applications can still have GUIs.)  If you *don't* need the standard I/O handles, there's no reason for the parent console to wait.

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't make an application that the command shell will automatically wait for which doesn't also create a console window if launched via the GUI.  (Though you can hide the console window immediately if you don't need it, the user will still see it appear and disappear.)  Yes, there are times when this is inconvenient, but it isn't really ever a major problem; the conventional solution is to have two different executables, one for GUI use and one for command-line use.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I know all of this, I'm not the OP. The problem is, that some programs may want to use stdio on demand but always have a GUI. It's a pretty common thing in *nix environments. If you start programs through some GUI menu no console window will pop up (even if the process writes something to stdio). But start the program from a terminal you can see the output. In Windows, as soon as your program needs stdio either a console window must be opened, or you spend a lot of time hacking the Console API to figure out if there's a console for your program and connect stdio in that case.

Comment: @datenwolf: yes, the "stdio on demand" scenario is one of the cases I alluded to in my comment to the OP, where the Windows approach is (mildly) inconvenient for the programmer.  Personally I still prefer that to the inconvenience of having to remember to background everything explicitly when I'm the user ... and of course *professional* GUI applications are expected to have proper log windows (or whatever) rather than using a console window, and for quick-and-dirty programming console mode is fine, so really this mostly only affects *nix ports, which tend to have bigger problems anyway. :-)

Comment: @datenwolf: note that the "separate GUI and console executable" approach also solves the "stdio on demand" scenario.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: personally I find those "proper log windows" infuriating; if they're optional and I can see errors on stderr, okay. But having only those? No, thank you! Because with this usually the output cannot be redirected conveniently into filter or search programs. The programs I write usually allow for vast amounts of diagnostics, and for that each line is prepended by some distinctive key, which allows to easily filter it. The powers of redirection and programs as `tee` allow to filter and display that in realtime with whatever program I see to fit best.

Comment: @datenwolf: interesting point.  Most Windows programs are written under the assumption that the user will not want to do that sort of troubleshooting themselves; I'm not saying that's necessarily a good thing, mind you, but it is the dominant paradigm.  FWIW, programs that do anticipate advanced troubleshooting from the end users do still have a number of options; a plugin model, for example, or named pipes - the simplest approach again being to have a separate executable for use in console mode.  (Or a shim that launches the GUI executable to do the real work.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston + datenwolf: Thanks a lot for these comments, those are the same problems I have struggled with (what if I sometimes want stderr, etc.). Could one of you (I'd suggest HarryJohnston, as he was first) write this into an answer (It can't be done, use two executables) so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Possible to have Win32 application block until it exits?

<strike>Call `CreateProcess` to create the process. This will yield a handle to the process in the `PROCESSINFORMATION` struct that is returned. Pass that process handle to `WaitForSingleObject` to wait until the process is signaled.</strike>

---

Based on the comments it seems that what you really want is an executable that will behave like a console app when its parent process is a console app. And behave like a GUI app otherwise. It's not possible to do both from a single executable. The target subsystem is determined by metadata in the executable file.

The standard way to handle this is to have two executables, each targeting the different subsystems. One a console app, the other a GUI app. The common examples of this are java.exe and javaw.exe, python.exe and pythonw.exe.

Comment: But if my app is a console application, it will always display a console (even when started from the desktop), which I don't want. If it is a GUI application, starting it from within a console will detach it immediately, and if I then call `CreateProcess` in my application, I'm already detached. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are driving at now. See update. Windows is just different from *nix.

Comment: +1.  Note that if you object to having two fully-fledged copies of what is essentially the same executable (such an objection may even be sensible in a few rare edge cases!) the console version can be a small application that launches the GUI version and waits for it to exit, as per David's original answer.  You can pass a command line argument to tell the GUI app to hook up to the parent console - that's a bit fiddly, but not horrifically so.

Comment: You can attach your Win32 application to console to provide stdout to the parent terminal application.

Answer (score 2):

> Using the w32 api, is it possible to program it so that my app displays a window, but the prompt is only returned after the user closes the window?

I think there are a few questions here.

First, how do you create a process in Windows? To create a process Windows, you use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Second, how does [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) work? [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) obviously creates a new process (like `calc.exe`), and it offers a lot of options to create the process. It also returns a `BOOL` to let you know if the call failed or succeeded.

In the case the call fails, you get a failure immediately. That's a "synchronous" failure, and you can continue moving along in your procedures.

In the case the call succeeds, your process is "detached" from the child. Its more like an "asynchronous" call to the function. You can synchronize with the child process, and you can learn that it has exited by waiting on the `hProcess` member of the [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

Third, not everyone starts processes from the command line. It might be started by clicking it on the desktop. This is true in the Linux/X11 (et al) world too.

Fourth, from the Windows command line, I believe you can use [`CALL`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) for other batch files. But I don't recall if it applies to programs, too.